# How to dismount an iSCSI volume

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

Anyone know a way of force dismounting an iSCSI volume from windows 2008? I need to redimension the iSCSI volume, but the applicance says it can only do this when its not in use, so I need to dismount it from windows. However I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I could just bring down the server and do it that way. However, now that I've hit the problem I'd like to find a solution. What would someone do on a big production server?

The volume doesn't have anything using it. Its shared using the standard admin share (like Z$) and a basic share. Noone is using it except for the windows Server process. However this should not prevent removal of the volume from the system, after all you an eject a DVD when it is shared.

Anyone any idea how to do this?

Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Disk Management, take the disks offline; in the iSCSI Control Panel, disconnect the target. If it is a favorite target, it will remount on the next reboot automatically. It can be manually remounted at any time.

Comment: Thanks for that - worked perfectly. Seems obvious now, don't know why I didn't think of it.